# hexbin in R gives overlapping bins for high xbins values

Tags: r

When working with hexbin in R and choosing a high number of xbins I get overlapping hexagonal bins, here is an example:

```
library(hexbin)
ss<-10000
x <- runif(ss,0,1)
y <- runif(ss)
bin <- hexbin(x, y,xbins=100,xbnds=c(0,1),ybnds=c(0,1),IDs=TRUE)
plot(bin)
```

Reading out the bins manually shows that the problem is not caused by the thickness of the polygons. Is this really a bug or I am just overlooking something ? In case it is a mistake what is a good alternative in R (can't use stat_binhex in ggplot since I need the bins as well as the full info which data point is contained in which bin for later export)?

NB: The overlaps become clearly visible when the plot is written in a pdf (maybe not in the GUI).

[image: irregular hexagons]

Comment: What's your evidence that they overlap? I ran your sample code and that's not obvious to me.

Comment: Lack of response to the very reasonable request for evidence is my reason for voting to close.

Comment: If you write as a PDF and zoom in I *can* see this. Have added a screenshot of a PDF at 400% mag.

Comment: @Spacedman, post as answer?

Comment: Have done, couldn't until it was un-closed!

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be caused by the plotting algorithm drawing hexagon borders with the same colour as the hexagon fill. When the hexagons are small the outlines overlap. Use `plot(bin, border=FALSE)` and I get perfect hexagonal hexagons in my zoomed PDF:

[image: perfect hexbins]

There may be some tiny hairlines between the cells but they are sub-pixel width.

I don't quite know what you meant by "Reading out the bins manually shows that the problem is not caused by the thickness of the polygons" but this seems to fix it.